# код вроде бы правильный,но не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip

простая инструкция. индекс массы тела. но читает только первое условие,какие бы ни были введены значения. почему он не работает?

```
massa = int(input('введите свой вес: '))
height = int(input('введите свой рост: '))

IMT = massa / (height) ** 2

if IMT < 18.5:
    print('дистрофия!')
elif IMT > 25:
    print('ожирение!')
else:
    if IMT <= 18.5 or IMT <= 25:
        print('в норме')
```

Comment: В каких единицах вводите рост? Ничего не настораживает? И третье условие внимательно прочитайте. if там вообще не нужен

Comment: нужно было рост поделить на сто. теперь работает.

Comment: и в третьем условии знак изменил. когда переписывал не заметил.

Comment: @Руслан третье условие не нужно, оно автоматически выполняется, если первые два `if` не сработали

Comment: да, действительно. просто можно принт написать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает. У Вас с формулой небольшая проблема была:

```
massa = int(input('введите свой вес в кг: '))
height = int(input('введите свой рост в сантиметрах: '))

height /= 100

IMT = massa / (height ** 2)

if IMT < 18.5:
  print('дистрофия!')
elif IMT > 25:
  print('ожирение!')
else :
  print('в норме')
```